TypeError: require is not a function( koa dependent formidable package error)
The formidable package version which is installed in the node-modules is 1.2.2 and the package.json has following packages:
"koa": "2.6.2",
"koa-bodyparser": "4.2.0",
"koa-compress": "5.1.1",
"koa-helmet": "4.0.0",
"koa-router": "7.4.0"

I integrated "koa-body" for handling multipart file uploads. However, upon launching the application, I encountered the below error. Since my application is quite dated and utilizes older koa-related packages, I opted for version 4.0.7 of koa-body as it seemed more appropriate.
Can anyone help what could be the fix for this issue?
Note: Application node version is 18
/Users/vinay/final-stories/stories/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:3

var crypto = require('crypto');

TypeError: require is not a function

at Object.../../node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js (/Users/vinay/final-stories/stories/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:3:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/vinay/final-stories/stories/applications/stories-service/build/webpack/bootstrap:685:1)
    at fn (/Users/vinay/final-stories/stories/applications/stories-service/build/webpack/bootstrap:59:1)
    at Object.../../node_modules/formidable/lib/index.js (/Users/vinay/final-stories/stories/node_modules/formidable/lib/index.js:1:20)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/vinay/final-stories/stories/applications/stories-service/build/webpack/bootstrap:685:1)
    at fn (/Users/vinay/final-stories/stories/applications/stories-service/build/webpack/bootstrap:59:1)
    at Object.../../node_modules/koa-body/index.js (/Users/vinay/final-stories/stories/node_modules/koa-body/index.js:18:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/vinay/final-stories/stories/applications/stories-service/build/webpack/bootstrap:685:1)
    at fn (/Users/vinay/final-stories/stories/applications/stories-service/build/webpack/bootstrap:59:1)
    at Object.../node-service/bodyParsers/jsonBodyParser.ts (/Users/vinay/final-stories/stories/applications/node-service/bodyParsers/jsonBodyParser.ts:2:1)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I want the application to start without any errors. So that I can test file upload

Not sure of the details of how you're bundling this.  You probably need to provide more details about how you've configured webpack.
